# how insert data from xml to mysql with loops

Tags: php, xml, tags

enter code here`hi how can help me ?
i have Problem in my script

i want save this xml file in the mysql db

the xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<STYLE>




<settings><style_name>default</style_name>
<style_version>1.0</style_version>
</settings>



<tpl>

<tpl_name>body</tpl_name>
<tpl_display_area>body</tpl_display_area>
<tpl_des>body</tpl_des>
<tpl_source><![CDATA[<
Body src
]]></tpl_source>



<tpl_name>footer</tpl_name><tpl_display_area>footer</tpl_display_area><tpl_des>footer</tpl_des>
<tpl_source>
<![CDATA[>

source Footer
]]>
</tpl_source>
<tpl_name>closing</tpl_name><tpl_display_area>close</tpl_display_area><tpl_des>closing</tpl_des><tpl_source><![CDATA[<center><h3>Our website close right now </h3></center>]]></tpl_source>




<tpl_name>display</tpl_name>
<tpl_display_area>display</tpl_display_area>
<tpl_des>display</tpl_des>
<tpl_source>
<![CDATA[{include file='db:header'}
{include file='db:body'}
{include file='db:footer'}]]>
</tpl_source>





<tpl_name>right block</tpl_name>
<tpl_display_area>right_block</tpl_display_area>
<tpl_des>right block</tpl_des>
<tpl_source><![CDATA[ right src ]]></tpl_source>
<tpl_name>left block</tpl_name>
<tpl_display_area>left_block</tpl_display_area>
<tpl_des>left block</tpl_des>
<tpl_source>
<![CDATA[<div class="left">
</div>]]>
</tpl_source>


<tpl_name>header</tpl_name>
<tpl_display_area>header</tpl_display_area>
<tpl_des>header</tpl_des><tpl_source><![CDATA[<head></head>]]></tpl_source>
</tpl>
</STYLE>
```

There was 7 templates i want to save settings tags in the style information table
one time only 
the table 
style_name varchar(255)
version varchar(255)

and want save all 7 template in mysql table

table Map

tpl_name varchar(255) 
tpl_display_area varchar(255) 
tpl_des varchar(255) 
tpl_source text

please help me

Comment: What exactly is your question, what part of the process are you stuck with?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SimpleXML-class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse the XML file and then use the [MySQLi-class](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to write the values in the Database.

Examples and Tutorials on both this things can be found in the PHP-Manual, the Comments in the PHP-Manual and on Google.

Step by Step:

1. Parse your XML-File and get the
   Values from it (save them in an
   Array)
2. Connect to your MySQL Database
3. Create a PreparedStatement for the
   Insert
4. Loop over your Array and Insert the
   Values in the Database
5. Close the Database connection

Comment: thanks for answerd my question but im trying all that i did not understand any thing if you can apply all that on my file and i will see it

Comment: We are not going to do your work. Read the Tutorials, check the Documentation and see if you can do it yourself. If you come up with any errors, feel free to ask here.

Comment: i dont want you to do my work only i want you to explain me how i can do this operation

Comment: Edited my post. This should give a basic idea of the workflow. Try to implement it and ask here, if you come up with any errors.